# Atom issue with PHP autocomplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm trying to use Atom as it's lightweight php editor. In addition to the core php autocomplete package I installed more packages here they are

[autocomplete-modules](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-modules)

[atom-autocomplete-php](https://atom.io/packages/atom-autocomplete-php)

[autocomplete-php](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-php)

[emmet-snippets-compatibility](https://atom.io/packages/emmet-snippets-compatibility)

[improved-autocomplete-php](https://atom.io/packages/improved-autocomplete-php)

[php-integrator-autocomplete-plus](https://atom.io/packages/php-integrator-autocomplete-plus)

I checked configurations and paths to php.exe and don't get any errors from any of them but still can't autocomplete php functions. If I type exp, array, priva, publ, func .... I don't get any suggestions. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There was a package php autocomplete base conflicting with these packages removed it and it's working now.